# How to select random accounts from dropdown using Jmeter Correlation

Tags: jmeter

I have designed my script using Co-relation with the help of regular expression. Here my scenario is login, go to the product search screen, there selects an account randomly and selects a product template and place the order. Here I have done the co-relation and run the scripts for 5 users by selecting provided accounts for each group. But I want to select a different account for each user. Might for 1st login he might select account 1, the second attempt, he might select account5, like that, and so on. How to select these accounts randomly. Here attaching the script and CSV format for the reference.

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp1Yh.png) [CSV Data_Set_Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YOWG.png)

[UI For Account selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5iUg.png)
[CSV File Inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfOCQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is splitting your CSV file into 2 separate ones so you will have `Account` column in the different file.

Once done you can use either [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) which has [`READ_MODE=RANDOM` parameter](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) or [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter) which is pretty much similar to the "normal" CSV Data Set Config but has possibility to return random entries.

Both plugins can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: But my worry here is for each user the accounts will not be the same. But in the .CSV file, I'm putting it as one only. For every user the accounts has to vary, in that case do I need to specify the account in .CSV. Here is my .csv file and also UI screenshots for reference. What I mean here is, I have different accounts, but in .csv I'm putting as 2000016. How to get these all accounts randomly when I'm running my script using correlation.

Comment: I have attached my UI For Account selection, CSV File Inputs images for reference. In csv file I'm sending it as 2000016. But for next time it should select as  3101525.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Blaze Meter's Random CSV Data Set Config plugin. It comes pretty handy in theese kind of situations. Almost a must have. You can even test your CSV before running the script.

https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md

[Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uepl2.png)